# How to check if a word contains only upper-case characters in a string with vb6

Tags: string, vb6

I'd like to find out if any word in a string contains only upper-case characters with using vb6..

Lets say ive a string like this: `"If you only knew the power of the DARKSIDE!"`

Here i wanna catch `"DARKSIDE"` regardless of punctuation marks.

So how can i achive that? This should be easy.. Though i couldn't figure with a blink of an eye..

Comment: Catch for what purposes? Some string methods can be made case insensitive.

Comment: I'd like to catch it for seperating from that string. Think it like `"Are you going to NORWAY?"` i ll get this string and seperate into these :
`"NORWAY", "Are you going to?"`.. Also this UCased characters can be contained anywhere! At start or end or in the middle of the string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim astrSplitItems() As String
astrSplitItems = Split(strInputString, " ")
For intX = 0 To UBound(astrSplitItems)
  If astrSplitItems(intX) = UCase(astrSplitItems(intX))
    //Found
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`If Chr("YOUR LETTER") = UCase(Chr("YOUR LETTER"))`

If it's true the Letter is UPPERCASE

Comment: This seems like an easy way but does it cause any problems with the punctuation marks?

Comment: The UCASE Function for example only affect letters.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression perhaps?
[vb6 regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html)

Comment: Nice one but first i should learn more about Regular expressions.. Thanks.